# pip can't find downloads

Tags: python, pip

pip used to word just fine, suddenly it stopped working, no matter what I try to download I get this message:

```
Downloading/unpacking django-grappelli
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement django-grappelli
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for django-grappelli
Storing complete log in /tmp/tmpUFetT_
```

this happens no matter what package I try to download, and it used to work up until around 2 days ago.

my setup is: os-x running a vagrant with precise64 running virtualenv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you access the internet on that vagrant machine? Try pinging:

`$ ping pypi.python.org`

and see if you receive a response.

Comment: ping pypi.python.org -
ping: unknown host pypi.python.org

Comment: You can't resolve pypi.python.org. You should set up networking on your vagrant box.

Comment: Restarted vagrant solved it, sometimes its just like a real computer, reset and it works, if we could only kick it as well, we would never have problems again ;)

Answer (score 0):

Restarted vagrant, I guess there was some problem with the network.